# What's wrong with this linq? trying to make an IN clause

Tags: c#, linq

Here's my linq

```
from G in Gestion select new
{
    GestionInicio = G.HoraInicio,
    GestionFin = G.HoraFin,
    hola = (from T in Tipificacion where T.IdTipificacion == G.IDTipificacion select T).FirstOrDefault().Nombre,
    LlamadaInicio = G.Llamada.HoraInicio,
    LlamadaFin = G.Llamada.HoraFin,
    Login = G.Llamada.Sesion.Usuario.Nombre
}
```

For me the code look's good but I cannot see the problem, That's why I asking this, And I know that the problem its related with the result of my sub linq.

Ok, so after see that I cannot make enough effort to explain this question

What I was trying to do with this linq it's a IN , in other words, in my sub linq I was passing the parameter to make a Join

Comment: Breathe...what is your question? What exactly is the problem/error that you are seeing?

Comment: Please put some effort into your question.

Comment: check the update of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Nick Strupat I realized that part of the problem was guarantees that the values wasn't null So I made a conditional and It worked like this

```
var gestiones = (from G in db.Gestion select new GestionesDataSet()
        {
           GestionInicio = G.HoraInicio,
           GestionFin = G.HoraFin,
           @Tipificacion = ((from T in db.Tipificacion select T).Where( x => x.IdTipificacion == G.IDTipificacion).Count() > 0 ?
                            (from T in db.Tipificacion where T.IdTipificacion == G.IDTipificacion select T.Nombre).FirstOrDefault() : ""),
           LlamadaInicio = G.Llamada.HoraInicio,
           LlamadaFin = G.Llamada.HoraFin,
           Login = G.Llamada.Sesion.Usuario.Nombre
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the error?

`FirstOrDefault` can return `null`. Trying to take the `Nombre` property from `null` will throw an exception.

We can only help if you show us the problem.

```
from g in Gestion select new
{
    GestionInicio = g.HoraInicio,
    GestionFin = g.HoraFin,
    hola = Tipificacion.FirstOrDefault(t => t.IdTipificacion == g.IDTipificacion).Nombre,
    LlamadaInicio = g.Llamada.HoraInicio,
    LlamadaFin = g.Llamada.HoraFin,
    Login = g.Llamada.Sesion.Usuario.Nombre
}
```

Comment: The problem its that I need to compare `Tipificacion` which is a Collection with the value of `Gestion` if i made the `firstOrDefault` before i was only compare with the first record

Comment: Check my answer, was based in your answer